# How to read a value from a website using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I´m new on JavaScript and I'm trying to do a small project for my website and I need some help.

I need to read the number of players that there are in my server from this website (https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/147.135.204.52) and them write in a my website.

I try this but it dosent work, can you see the problem?

```js
<script>
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    setInterval(queryJugadores, 5000);
  queryJugadores();
    $(".navbar-brand").tooltip({placement: "bottom", html: true});
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});

  function queryJugadores() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/147.135.204.52",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(res){
        if (res["status"]) {
          actualizarJugadores(res["players"]["online"]);
        }
      }
    });
  }

function actualizarJugadores(num) {
  var digitos = ("" + num).split("");
  var elem = $(".cuenta-jugadores").children("dd");
  elem.empty();
  for (index = 0; index < digitos.length; index++){
    elem.append("<span>" + digitos[index] + "</span>")
  }
  var color = "#43DBE7";

  if (num==0) {
    color = "#d9534f"
  }
  elem.children("span").css("background-color",color);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<dl class="cuenta-jugadores">
    <dd>
     <span>0</span>
     <span>1</span>
     <span>2</span>
     <span>3</span>
    </dd>
   </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: "I try this but it dosent work, can you see the problem?" What doesn't work about it? Be specific with your problem/question.

Comment: The problem is that the code can´t take the number of players from the website. I have followed a tutorial to make it, as I said, I´m new in JavaScript. Many Thanks

Comment: The code works fine for me (after removing the accidental script tag in the js). Open the console and see if you can any errors. And make sure you include jquery in your html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works just fine.

You had some extra code at the top that looks like it needs the jQueryUI library https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ and refers to elements ( navbar-brand ) that you haven't included in your html. I removed that code.

```js
  $(document).on("ready", function() {
    setInterval(queryJugadores, 5000);
    queryJugadores();
  });

function queryJugadores() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/147.135.204.52",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(res) {
      if (res["status"]) {
        actualizarJugadores(res["players"]["online"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

function actualizarJugadores(num) {
  var digitos = ("" + num).split("");
  var elem = $(".cuenta-jugadores").children("dd");
  elem.empty();
  for (index = 0; index < digitos.length; index++) {
    elem.append("<span>" + digitos[index] + "</span>")
  }
  var color = "#43DBE7";

  if (num == 0) {
    color = "#d9534f"
  }
  elem.children("span").css("background-color", color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <dl class="cuenta-jugadores">
    <dd>
      <span>0</span>
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing "method" to "type" in the Ajax Syntax, I can't see any other errors.

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  setInterval(queryJugadores, 5000);
  queryJugadores();
  /*
  $(".navbar-brand").tooltip({
    placement: "bottom",
    html: true
  });
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();*/
});


function queryJugadores() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://use.gameapis.net/mc/query/players/147.135.204.52",
    type: "GET",
    /* dataType: 'json', */
    success: function(res) {
      if (res["status"]) {
        actualizarJugadores(res["players"]["online"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

function actualizarJugadores(num) {
  var digitos = ("" + num).split("");
  var elem = $(".cuenta-jugadores").children("dd");
  elem.empty();
  for (index = 0; index < digitos.length; index++) {
    elem.append("<span>" + digitos[index] + "</span>")
  }
  var color = "#43DBE7";

  if (num == 0) {
    color = "#d9534f"
  }
  elem.children("span").css("background-color", color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="cuenta-jugadores">
  <dd>
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: `You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.` I sincerely hope it's not this.